# how to show news without marquee tag

Tags: javascript, html

Without use of marquee tag I want to show news like below code.I want to use JavaScript instead of marquee tag. How to use JavaScript to do this?

```
   <marquee style="width: 292px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);" align="top" behavior="scroll" direction="up" onmouseout="this.start();" onmouseover="this.stop();" scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="25" truespeed="" id="mSpeed" bgcolor="#f1f2ec" height="500">


                    <div style="padding: 5px; height: 153px;" class="workshopDesc bottomHorzLine ">
                        <div class="workshopTitle" align="left">Financial Management Training</div>

                        <div class="workshopDate"><font color="#ff0000" size="1"><strong>Date: Friday, May 28, 2010</strong></font></div>
                        <div class="workshopRPName"><strong>Resource Person: Saif Rahman<br>Independent Consultant in Business Case Development and Financial Management</strong></div>

                        <div class="workshopDesc">Mr. Saif Rahman is an Independent Consultant in Business Case Development and Financial Management with rich experience of corporate sectors of both North America and South-East Asia....
                        <div style="float: right; width: 150px;" align="right"><img src="images/icons_more.gif" align="absmiddle" width="12" height="12" hspace="5"><a href="http://BdjobsTraining.com/workshop_formate.asp?TID=518" class="workshopLink" target="_blank">Click here for detail</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
            </marquee>
```

Comment: A good news - `marquee` is making a comeback in CSS3 - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/, so we won't need any JavaScript hacks anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[javascript news ticker script](http://www.hypergurl.com/newsticker.html)** if you don't want to use the `marquee` tag. Instructions are there on the link.

Comment: i need to show news scrolling from bottom to top not left to right.want to write news under the div and want to control scrolling by javascript same as mine  given syntax.