# How to resolve white space while using marquee tag

Tags: jquery

In my website i am displaying Live news (scrolling functionality) by using marquee tag .

The issue i am facing once the scrolling is completed ,  a white space is being shown

Please see the image with respect to the issue

[image]

Some part of my code

```
function displaylivenews() {
    var s = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < latestnewsresponse.length; i++) {
                s += '<li><div class="itemTitle"><a href="' + latestnewsresponse[i].link + '"  target="_">' + latestnewsresponse[i].title + "</a></div>";
                s += '<div class="itemDate">' + latestnewsresponse[i].pub_date + "</div>";
                mysource = latestnewsresponse[i].link.split("://")[1].split('/')[0].replace(/(www.)|(.com)/g, '');
                s += '<div class="Source">' + mysource + "</div>";
                s += '</li>'
            }
            jQuery("#livenewsRss").html("<ul class='feedEkList'>" + s + "</ul>");


    }
```

and this is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6n8ecLq6/5

Could you please let em know how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Using that JSFiddle (on Chrome on Windows), I am not getting any extra whitespace like you're getting for some reason. Can you please share the platform and browser you're using?

Comment: Do you mean that the marquee tag is blank for a very very short timeframe when the news ticker has to start again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marquee` is a deprecated and not a valid **HTML** tag. You can use many jQuery plugins to do. One of it is [**jquery easy ticker**](https://github.com/vaakash/jquery-easy-ticker). There are many more!

Answer (score 1):

**When i search for marquee tag i found a lot of warnings like** :

> **Obsolete**
> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.
>
> **Note:**
> The HTML  tag may not be supported by various browsers so its not recommended to rely on this tag, instead you can use Javascript and CSS to create such effects.

Take a look at the following questions :

- **[marquee tag still works, is it okay to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520840/marquee-tag-still-works-is-it-okay-to-use-it)**.
- **[Is the marquee HTML element supported by all browsers yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964491/is-the-marquee-html-element-supported-by-all-browsers-yet)**.

You can see that the `marquee` tag it was DEPRECATED by the W3C (**[W3C Obsolete features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete)**), and you can't find any direct solution for the blank space relative with tag over the web, but fortunately you can find a lot of similar plugins (JQuery, javascript, CSS3) do the work everywhere, e.g:

- Take a look at the answers of the following question posted here in stackoverflow  **[Continuously scrolling horizontal ticker containing images in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294048/continuously-scrolling-horizontal-ticker-containing-images-in-jquery)**, there's really several options suggested there.
- You can use also **jdNewsScroll** plugin, see the demo **[HERE](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdNewsScroll/1.1/jdNewsScroll-demo.html)** and the source **[HERE](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdNewsScroll/1.1/)**.
- You can try also **[javascript news ticker script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887533/how-to-show-news-without-marquee-tag)** suggested in the following question **[how to show news without marquee tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887533/how-to-show-news-without-marquee-tag)**.
- Find more than **[20 jQuery News Ticker & News Scroller Plugin Example](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-news-ticker/)**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your `latestnewsresponse` is empty, you will set a new empty `<ul>` element. The white space might be the padding/margin of this empty element.

```
if (s != "")
   jQuery("#livenewsRss").html("<ul class='feedEkList'>" + s + "</ul>");
```

Comment: thanks i have used your code , but still i am getting the same issue .

Comment: I don't see the white space on your fiddle

Comment: There are 6 items , let them scroll completely , then you will see the white space (next iteration )

Comment: Sorry but I don't see it. Where is it supposed to be ? Bottom of the moving div ? left of `ul`/`li` ?

Comment: i have removed the scroll delay , please see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6n8ecLq6/5/  , you will the white space issue iteration after iteration .